# How does decoder deal with pad tokens in input encodings

Tags: transformer-model, decoder

Hi I am working on Transformer models and have one doubt regarding decoding and auto regressive generation.

My input sequence has pad tokens at the end and during encoding, it uses an attention mask to deal with pad tokens. However, during decoding, the decoder only takes encodings and decoder_input_ids and predicts the next token. How does decoder deal with pad tokens in input encodings as it even works without passing encoder_attention_mask to it.

Decoder works without passing encoder_attention_mask.